# Heredoc to insert data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am unable to create a table belonging to an exsisting database in order to connect them. Within the code I use heredoc syntax in order to insert element in the table that supposed to be created

```html
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);?>
<?php 
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'pippo', 'pluto') or
     die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters'.);
 mysql_select_db('moviesite', $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
 
 //crea la tabella reviews
 $query = 'CREATE TABLE reviews (
         review_movie_id  INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   review_date      DATE             NOT NULL,
   reviewer_name     VARCHAR(255)     NOT NULL,
   review_comment   VARCHAR(255)     NOT NULL,
   review_rating    TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
   KEY  (review_movie_id)
   )
   ENGINE=MyISAM';
 mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
 
 //inserisce i nuovi dati nella tabella reviews
 $query = <<<ENDSQL
    INSERT INTO reviews
     (review_movie_id, review_date, reviewer_name, review_comment,
       review_rating)
 VALUES
     (1, "2008-09-23", "Jhon Doe", "I thought this was a great movie
       Even though my girlfriend made me see it against my will.", 4),
  (1, "2008-09-23", "Billy Bob", "I liked Eraserhead better.", 2),
  (1, "2008-09-28", "Peppermint Pappy", "I wish I'd have seen it
       sooner!", 5),
  (2, "2008-09-23", "Marvin Martian", "This is my favorite movie. I 
       didn't wear my flair to the movie but I loved it anyway.", 5),
  (3, "2008-09-23", "George B.", "I liked this movie, even though I
       Thought it was an informational video from my travel agent.", 3)
ENDSQL;
mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

echo 'Moviesite successfully updated!';
?>
```

I've also added error reporting but it reports nothing at all! please help me to get over this issue. The only thing that the server returns is a 500 error

Comment: Two items of feedback: (1) a 500 server error usually means there is a more specific PHP error that is logged in your error logs. Dig into the end of your logs to find out what that is. (2) After you set `$query` using the heredoc, echo it out to see if it looks OK. Also, try running it manually in your database (e.g. MySQL console or phpMyAdmin) to find if it is the query that is the problem.

Comment: It's not the problem, but the `reviews` table doesn't seem to have a primary key, only a foreign key. Tables should generally have a primary key, so rows are uniquely identifiable.